# JavaFx with scene builder: edit integer column in tableview

Tags: user-interface, javafx

I try to make an editable table. But I don't know how to edit integer column. These codes I used are fine to work on String column.

```
Name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table, String>("Name"));
    Name.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());

    Name.setOnEditCommit(
            (TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Table, String> t) ->
                ( t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                ).setName(t.getNewValue())
            );
```

Comment: Please be more specific on what is not working! Are there any exceptions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set the proper cellFactory:

```
    integerColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new IntegerStringConverter()));
```